# WPF 3D extrude "a bitmap"

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, vector

I'm looking for a way to simulate a projector in wpf 3D :

i've these **"in"** parameters :

- beam shape : a black and white bitmap file
- beam size ( ex : 30 °)
- beam color
- beam intensity ( dimmer )
- projector position (x,y,z)
- beam position (pan(x),tilt(y) relative to projector)

First i was thinking of using light object but it seem that wpf can't do that

So, now i think that i can make for each projector a polygon from my bitmap...

First i need to convert the black and white bitmap to vector.
Only Simple shape ( bubble, line,dot,cross ...)

Is there any WPF way to do that ? Or maybe a external program file (freeware);

then i need to build the polygon, with the shape of the converted bitmap ,
color , size , orientation in parameter.

i don't know how can i defined the lenght of the beam , and if it can be infiny ...

To show the beam result, i think of making a room ( floor , wall ...) and beam will end to these wall...

i don't care of real light render ( dispersion ...) but the scene render has to be real time and at least 15 times / second (with probably from one to 100 projectors at the same time), information about position, angle,shape,color will be sent for each render...

Well so, i need sample for that, i guess that all of these things could be useful for other people

If you have sample code :

Convert Bitmap to vector
Extrude vectors from one point with a angle parameter until collision of a wall
Set x,y position of the beam depend of the projector position
Set Alpha intensity of the beam, color

Maybe i'm totally wrong and WPF is not ready for that , so advise me about other way ( xna,d3D ) with sample of course ;-)

Thanks you

Comment: thanks i know it of course and some others (martin, magic 3d )!!! but they don't give the source code so it doesn't help me much ...

Comment: http://www.boutique-electroconcept.com/images/Mojo_Scan_I_Gobo.jpg here's what i would like ( not as realistic of course ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seam to do  "light patterns on the floor" there is two way

use a spotlight with a cookie. Or Projector with a custom shader that does additive blending.

or manually creating partially transparent polygons to simulate the "rays". and i need some example for one or the other case

Answer (score 0):

I would represent the "beam" as a light. I'd load the bitmap into a stencil buffer. You should be able to do this with OpenGL, DirectX, or XNA. AFAIK, WPF doesn't give access to the hardware for stencil buffers or shadows.